# How to use ValueAnimator#ofFloat

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I'm so confused as to how ValueAnimator works in Android. Here's a code snippet (pseudo):

```
Log("animating: ", start, end);
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(start, end);
animator.setUpdateListener(() -> {
    Log("update", animation.getAnimatedFraction());
});
animator.start();
```

I see the following in my logs:

```
animating: 0.0 to 1.0
update: 0.0
update: 0.05
..
update: 1.0

animating: 1.0 to 0.0
update: 0.0 (wtf)
update: 0.05
..
update: 1.0

animating: 0.5 to 1.0
update: 1.0 (wtf)
update: 1.0
```

Can someone explain to me why my update function is getting these strange values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you use `getAnimatedValue` ? It's exactly that value that calculated while property changing, it's not a fraction:

```
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        Float value = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        Log("update", String.valueOf(value));
    }
});
```

Comment: Aha, you are right, getAnimatedValue is the correct call.

Comment: I still have the issue where trying to go from 0.5 to 1.0 only gives 1.0 updates, but that seems to be a different issue

Comment: figured out my other issue, i was accidentally setting duration to 0 for those cases -__- thanks!